# Query to get special price values in sitecore

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to get all the products under my "product root" where `"Special Price"` field value should not be `empty` and value greater than `0`

And I have written the following query

```
/sitecore/content/corsair/Data/product_root/descendant::*[@@templateid='myid']/child::*[@Special Price > 0]
```

But it is displaying only few products even whether the criteria not satisfied(I have modified their values manually, yet displaying them)

Is my query right for my need, need help

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of queries when your field contains spaces you need to escape using dashes. 
Please change you query to be something like above one

/sitecore/content/corsair/Data/product_root//*[@@templateid='{3458997D-D403-4CCC-BA1D-FC119D3BAA61}' and @#Special price# >='10']

Above query is searching on all descendants of product_root with a given templateid and special price greater than 10. 
Please also check below links about sitecore queries:

http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/05/Sitecore-Query-Cheat-Sheet.aspx

Comment: The problem is whatever the query is it is giving only few products as outpou. I know there are many more

Comment: how many? can you test your queries on developer center.here is the link: http://example.com/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE

Comment: I'm testing on developer center only

Comment: How many results you have? Can you check value of <setting name="Query.MaxItems" ...>

Comment: It is returning around 50 but I have 70

Comment: Can you check on english version if you add a new item and run the query is increasing number of results?